# Mysql 80 client setup

Tags: mysql, freebsd

Hi everyone I don't understand BSD . MySQL client setup error .Do not try to explain the cause of the error because I won't understand just code thank's.(my English is bad)

```
/usr/ports/databases/mysql80-client/work/mysql- 
8.0.14/mysys/stacktrace.cc:258:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 
'backtrace'
 int n = backtrace(addrs, array_elements(addrs));
       ^
/usr/ports/databases/mysql80-client/work/mysql- 
8.0.14/mysys/stacktrace.cc:262:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 
'backtrace_symbols'
 if ((strings = backtrace_symbols(addrs, n))) {
                ^
/usr/ports/databases/mysql80-client/work/mysql- 
8.0.14/mysys/stacktrace.cc:268:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'backtrace_symbols_fd'
backtrace_symbols_fd(addrs, n, fileno(stderr));
           ^
 3 errors generated.
*** [mysys/CMakeFiles/mysys.dir/stacktrace.cc.o] Error code 1

make[3]: stopped in /usr/ports/databases/mysql80-client/work/.build
 1 error

make[3]: stopped in /usr/ports/databases/mysql80-client/work/.build
*** [mysys/CMakeFiles/mysys.dir/all] Error code 2

make[2]: stopped in /usr/ports/databases/mysql80-client/work/.build
1 error

make[2]: stopped in /usr/ports/databases/mysql80-client/work/.build
*** [all] Error code 2

make[1]: stopped in /usr/ports/databases/mysql80-client/work/.build
1 error

make[1]: stopped in /usr/ports/databases/mysql80-client/work/.build
===> Compilation failed unexpectedly.
Try to set MAKE_JOBS_UNSAFE=yes and rebuild before reporting the failure to
the maintainer.
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/ports/databases/mysql80-client
root@black:/usr/ports/databases/mysql80-client #
```

Answer (score 2):

Install the binary package(as root)

```
# pkg install mysql80-client
```

See [4.4.3. Installing and Removing Packages](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/pkgng-intro.html).